# Indirect reference in bash, why isn't this working?

Tags: bash, function

I'm trying to tidy up one of my bash scripts by using a function for something that happens 6 times. The script sets a number of variables from a config.ini file and then lists them and asks for confirmation that the user wishes to proceed with these predefined values. If not, it steps through each variable and asks for a new one to be entered (or to leave it blank and press enter to use the predefined value). This bit of code accomplishes that:

```
echo Current output folder: $OUTPUT_FOLDER
echo -n "Enter new output folder: "
read C_OUTPUT_FOLDER
if [ -n "$C_OUTPUT_FOLDER" ]; then OUTPUT_FOLDER=$C_OUTPUT_FOLDER; fi
```

The idea is to set `$OUTPUT_FOLDER` to the value of `$C_OUTPUT_FOLDER` but only if `$C_OUTPUT_FOLDER` is not null. If `$C_OUTPUT_FOLDER` IS null, it will not do anything and leave `$OUTPUT_FOLDER` as it was for use later in the script.

There are 6 variables that are set from the config.ini so this block is currently repeated 6 times. I've made a function `new_config ()` which is as follows:

```
new_config () {
  echo Current $1: ${!2}
  echo -n "Enter new $1: "
  read $3
  if [ -n "${!3}" ]; then $2=${!3}; fi
}
```

I'm calling it with (in this instance):

```
new_config "output folder" OUTPUT_FOLDER C_OUTPUT_FOLDER
```

When I run the script, it has an error on the `if` line:

```
./test.sh: line 9: OUTPUT_FOLDER=blah: command not found
```

So, what gives? The block of code in the script works fine and (in my quite-new-to-bash eyes), the function should be doing exactly the same thing.

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do, but the problem is in `$2=${!3}`.

Comment: Yeah, I figured as much, thanks. I don't get why it seems to be referencing the variables, so `$2=${!3}` expands to `OUTPUT_FOLDER=$C_OUTPUT_FOLDER` (because the error mentions `OUTPUT_FOLDER=blah`, "blah" being what I entered as the new output folder) but then throws up this error. I want to give the user the opportunity to change any of the predefined variables in the script (without editing the config.ini file directly) on each run. So if they enter a new value, set `$OUTPUT_FOLDER` to it, otherwise (if `$C_OUTPUT_FOLDER` is blank) leave `$OUTPUT_FOLDER` as it was defined in the ini file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that bash splits the command into tokens *before* variable substitution, see http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_01_04.html#sect_01_04_01_01. Specifically there's rules for POSIX shells that make assignments a special case for tokenization: ["If all the characters preceding '=' form a valid name (see XBD Name), the token ASSIGNMENT_WORD shall be returned."](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_10) - it's the ASSIGNMENT_WORD token that triggers the assignment path. It doesn't repeat the tokenization after variable substitution, which is why your code doesn't work.

You can get your code to work like so:

```
new_config () {
  echo Current $1: ${!2}
  echo -n "Enter new $1: "
  read $3
  if [[ -n "${!3}" ]]; then echo setting "$2='${!3}'"; eval "$2='${!3}'"; fi
}

new_config "output folder" OUTPUT_FOLDER C_OUTPUT_FOLDER
echo $OUTPUT_FOLDER
```

As @chepner points out, you can use `declare -g $2="${!3}"` instead of eval here, and on newer bash versions that's a better answer. Unfortunately `declare -g` requires bash 4.2, and even though that's 3 years old it's still not everywhere - for example, OS X Mavericks is stuck on 3.2.51.

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you! That bash guide for beginners also looks very useful.

Comment: Use `declare` instead of `eval`. You don't need to actually evaluate any code; you just need to expand the value of `$2` and `$3` (indirectly) prior to making the assignment.

Comment: I'll edit that in, but the actual equivalent (declare -g) requires a recent bash (surprisingly, OSX is still using one from 2007).

Comment: In bash 3.2 you can use `printf -v` to assign a value to an expanded name.